# build.gradle changes for git submodule

Tags: git, maven, ant, gradle

Source Tree is as follows:

```
core               // root
  .gitmodules     // this has box-sdk as submodule
  box-sdk          // git submodule
     BoxJavaLibraryV2     // Box related files
```

I also created `settings.gradle`

```
include 'box-sdk:BoxJavaLibraryV2'
```

My build.gradle

```
compile project(':box-sdk:BoxJavaLibraryV2')
```

At this point I was able to compile and build root project with box as dependency.

Problem started when I tried to checkin and checkout again the whole project. I did following:

I was able to check in `.gitmodules` and `box-sdk directory`. But I was not able to checkin BoxJavaLibraryV2.

```
It errored out saying BoxJavaLibraryV2 is a submodule
```

I checked out root again separately where I get both .gitmodules and box-sdk (without BoxJavaLibraryV2)

Then to build my project I had to do manually:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
gradle war
```

What changes and where I need to do to eliminate init and update steps.

What I am looking for is:

when I checkout `git master`, **the whole project with submodules** should build with `gradle war`

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can have only one step:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Second, Gradle itself has an open issue (since 2010) to integrate that step:
[GRADLE-21: "Streamline issues with including the build as a git submodule"](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/GRADLE-21).

A `git clone --recursive` would clone:checkout your repo *with* submodules checked out.

The issue suggests various ways, one of them being making a gradle wrapper (which would call the appropriate git submodule command before calling `gradle`).