# How to update the git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have 2 projects. "`MyProg`" and "`SubProj`".
Both projects are on Bitbucket.

One project is submodule to the second. The problem is that when I pull changes in the main project, the changes submodule are not pulled.

Perhaps it should be, or did I do something wrong?
How do I do that when you upgrade one project *and* pull the second project's change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that when I pull changes in the main project, the changes submodule not pull

Don't forget that a submodule is a **fixed** reference to a SHA1: it is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309).

It doesn't move unless you have configured that submodule to follow a branch.
(See "[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)" and "[Git submodule new version update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17199855/6309)")
In that case, this would update it:

```
git submodule update --init --remote
```

Don't forget to add, commit and push (in the parent repo) the new reference if the submodule was updated to a more recent SHA1.

Comment: I do not quite understand you. my English is not very good. Can I do this? when I update the main project, I want my sub module automatically updated, too, if it was changed.

Comment: @PavelPetrashov follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309, and *then* updating your main project will include the latest of your submodule (provinding you run the command `git submodule update --recursive --remote` after `git pull`).

Comment: can you know if I can automate this in gradle?

Comment: @PavelPetrashov not easily: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21374600/6309 and read more about the problem at https://jira.spring.io/browse/GRADLE-21